# Bootstrap Gutters seem not to be working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Am trying Bootstrap 3.

2 columns but they are not between gutters.

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 box">
        <div>
          <h3 class="green size-16">Test</h3>
        </div><!--first stack-->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae tellus cursus, porttitor nisi vitae, laoreet metus. Pellentesque felis sapien, ullamcorper vel massa vel, pharetra efficitur diam.
        </div><!--second stack-->
      </div><!--first box-->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 box">
        <div>
          <h3 class="green size-16">Test</h3>
        </div><!--first stack-->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae tellus cursus, porttitor nisi vitae, laoreet metus. Pellentesque felis sapien, ullamcorper vel massa vel, pharetra efficitur diam.
        </div><!--second stack-->
      </div><!--second box-->
</div>
```

Bootstrap css in head and js at bottom of the body. I do see the padding showing on inspect element, but all boxes are glued to one another so it looks like all in a box.

I might have overlooked smthing, but I tested on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t57jdu5y/) and it showed that it worked correctly. It is strange that on html file, it wasnt working as it should.

help appreciated

**One more thing**
Even with cheating addition to css: margin: 15px, the col-md-4 boxes becomes 2 columns instead of 3 columns. Is it because of the wrapper being in max-width: 1200px?

Comment: Is all your provided code inside a <div class="container"></div>? If not, this is likely your issue.

Comment: @celmar - yes it is in container but still nothing :(

Comment: The next thing to check is if you have any css which is overriding padding or margin on any of your classes.

Comment: @celmar - yes i did check but all does not have padding to box.. hmm

Comment: Would you be able to provide your entire html code/css? Unfortunately, without more information, I can't help too much.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t57jdu5y/2/ --@Celmar

Comment: [Run Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/#in-the-browser) and see if it finds anything.

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine, the padding is being set on each column correctly. Background will fill up to padding, perhaps this is your issue. If so, just wrap everything in a div within the column and set a background on that.

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.bootply.com/HpDMh1oBK7 Let me know if this solves your issue so I can submit it as an answer for anyone who looks at this question in the future.

Comment: @Celmar - somewhat class inner with margin works. not sure if it is correct or not but it works. thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is correct and it's how Bootstrap is designed. **The padding affects the content within the grid divs**, not the div themselves. I've tweaked your example and made a bootply (my prefered tool - sorry) http://www.bootply.com/8hj7p5Engy.

The content is nicely "guttered" and padded away from neighbor content, but when you add a background or border to the div, then it looks off.

If you're looking for bordered or colored containers around your content, you should probably look at using a Bootstrap `.well` or `.panel`